# socket between c++ and java

Tags: java, c++, sockets

I wrote a server in c++ and to send messages I set the follow thread:

```
void *send(void* v)
{
    string m="";
    while(true)
    {
        std::cin >> m;
        write(socketfd, static_cast<void*>(&m), m.length()+1);
    }
}
```

to read the messages I wrote the follwing code:

```
public void recieve() throws IOException{
    while (true){
        if(input.hasNext()){
            viewText.setText(viewText.getText() + "\nSever: "+input.nextLine());
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void run() {
    try {
        recieve();
        socket.close();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

When I write into the variable M and press enter, nothing happen. But when I close the server, all the values of m i wrote before are printed as one string.

I Apologize for the incorrect English.
tnks

Comment: Is `write(socketfd, static_cast<void*>(&m), m.length()+1);` really working? Shouldn't it be `write(socketfd, m.c_str(), m.length());`? (supposing `string` means `std::string`)

Comment: also void *send(void\* v) should be changed to: void send() (in your case)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not knowing the type of `input` in your Java code, the method name `nextLine()` suggests that it will read a whole line. Line is sequence of characters which is terminated with newline character. On the other hand, no newline character will be stored via `std::cin >> m;`, so all data until terminating the sending side will be treated as one line.

To send multiple lines, you should use another way such as `std::getline(std::cin, m);` to read input and add newline characters if the way drops them.

Answer (score 4):

```
string m="";
```

`m` is a class called `std::string`.

```
static_cast<void*>(&m),
```

`&m` is the address of the `std::string` structure. It is not the address of the actual string that this class represents. You need to obtain the actual contents of the string class, and write that to the socket:

```
write(socketfd, m.c_str(), m.length()+1);
```

This is an over-simplified example, but you can think of a `std::string` as a class that looks like this:

```
class std::string {

    char *data;
    size_t length;

    // ...
};
```

Writing the physical address of this pointer, and other internal contents of the string class to the socket accomplishes nothing useful. You need to obtain the actual string data.

Comment: While this *feels* like it ought to be the right answer, I am a bit suspicious that the OP said " when I close the server, all the values of m i wrote before are printed as one string." - which isn't the behaviour I would expect.

Comment: There's probably buffering going on in the Java classes, too. But the C++ code is definitely wrong.

Comment: thanks sam. I changed my code as you said. but the problem still not solved :(

Answer (score 1):

```
std::cin >> m;
```

Will only read until the first instance of whitespace, or a newline if only one word is written:

```
input.nextLine()
```

reads until a newline is entered, and spaces don't terminate. To do the equivalent in C++, you need to use [`getline(std::cin, m)`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) like this (Don't forget to include `<string>`):

```
getline(std::cin, input)
```

Comment: thank you MikeCAT and Arnav Borborah!
as you said, the problem was in the new line.